# Rotate a vector by another vector, using OpenTK library methods

Tags: c#, opengl, vector-graphics, opentk

I have a wall in 3d space with the normal vector `(0, 0, -1)` and I need to rotate this vector by a *rotation vector*. For example, rotating by would `(0, Math.PI, 0)` would result in `(0, 0, 1)`.

I'm not interested in coding vector operations to perform the math myself, rather I'd prefer to know which operations are required, and then to call them from the extensive OpenTK math class.

After searching the internet and other related questions, I accept that these concepts are beyond my current mathematical competence. While I understand understanding vector math is very important in 3d programming, time is very precious and at this point, my main priority is developing my program quickly.

The model matrix for each wall is created with:

```
Matrix4 modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rotation.X) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rotation.Y) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rotation.Z) * Matrix4.CreateTranslation(position);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "rotation vector".

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake. But did you read the question? I know you know a lot about OpenGL and surely you understand what I mean. I have a quad whose model matrix is determined by matrix operations on a vector3 representing it's rotation. I'd like to determine a directional vector for the quad based on that "rotation vector".